# How to insert <br> tag in pandas when appending two dataframes

Tags: python, html, pandas, dataframe

I am writing multiple dataframes to same html file. But I want to create a blank white space between dataframes thas been writeen to html file. How to insert (blank line) 
 kind of html tag when appending dataframes..

What I tried:

```
with open(r"c:\csv\instancetest.html", 'w') as _file:
     _file.write(df.to_html() + "\n\n" + df1.to_html()
```

Comment: Instead of `"\n\n"` use `"<br>"`, no?

Comment: it gave TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str' error when i used <br>

Comment: You did `df.to_html() + "<br>" + df1.to_html()`? I cannot reproduce your error with this code.

Comment: My bad, its working now, you are correct, I missed out some other syntax in same line... thank for your solution...possibly you can add your comment in answer :) so that i can mark it complete and answered. Total credit to you for helping me :)

Comment: No problem. Glad it worked out. I'll just vote to close it as trivially resolved, but you're welcome to post a [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) if you want.